# How to loop a json object in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json object as below:
idp =

[image]

I want to loop over this object to extract just the uuid and origin fields. I have written this python script:

```
x = 0

for x in idp:

    idpUUID = idp['dataObject'][x]['uuid']

    idpName = idp['dataObject'][x]['origin']

    if x>50:

        break
```

But in the for loop for x=0, the value of x is taken as "dataObject" and not integers to loop.

Is there any other way I can loop in the json object so that I can get all uuid fields in idpUUID and origin fields in idpName?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put the Json data as text (with correct formatting) and not as picture? So we can copy-paste it

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i76789884/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Terminology correction: You're attempting to loop over a dictionary, not a JSON object. `idp` may have started out as JSON (J=JavaScript) text but is now a Python dictionary.

Comment: what is the point of the if statement? this will make the loop terminate after one iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you traverse a dictionary in Python, the value of `x` will be each key in the dictionary. Your dictionary only has one key (dataObject) so it sets this as the value of x. You can modify your code like this:

```py
for x in idp['dataObject']:
    idpUUID = x['uuid']
    idpName = x['origin']

    # do something with your data here
```

Instead of traversing the dictionary, this will traverse the list that is the value of the key `dataObject` in your dictionary. With each iteration of the loop, x will be one of the objects in the list.

When you become more advanced with Python, you can make this code even more concise with list comprehension like in Zombro's answer.

Answer (score 0):

two flavors to start

```
[{'uuid': d['uuid'], 'origin': d['origin']} for d in d['dataObject']]
```

```
[{ k: v for k,v in d.items() if k in ['uuid', 'origin']} for d in d['dataObject']]
```